# Collapsing 'Non-Link' items in Twitter Bootstrap 3 Responsive Navbar

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a responsive ***fixed-top* navbar** (using *Twitter Bootstrap **3***) as follows:

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header"><a href="/"><img src="/images/citylightslogo.png" alt="logo"  id="cllogo"/></a>
      </div>

        **<h1 id="topline2">&bull;&nbsp; Tagline1 &nbsp;</h1>
        <h1 id="topline3">&bull;&nbsp; Address  &nbsp;&bull; Call Anytime! xxx xxx xxxx </h1>
         <div id="adspace" >
        <h1 id="headline33" class =".visible-xs" >100% Satisfaction Guaranteed!&nbsp; Call us Anytime!  </h1>
         </div>

          <div id="logospace"><a href="http://www.angieslist.com"><img src="/images/ab2.gif" alt="logo"  id="alogo2"/></a><a href="/"><img src="/images/ab2.gif" alt="logo"  id="alogo3"/></a>
          </div>**

         </div>
        </div>
```

I just want to make sure that I am learning this *correctly*: Currently, the elements in **bold** above overflow all over the place (into other rows) when collapsed.

**Question:** How could I make sure that they are either *invisible* when collapsed or *partially visible* in mobile or tablet screens when collapsed?

Is the fact that I am not including those elements in the "navabar-header" class the problem or should I be wrapping them in a separate div to begin with (if so what div?)?

It seems the bootstrap docs are focused on explaining how to make **navbar links** *responsive* and I cannot seem to find anything on **making non-link content (like headers) responsive** as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using `navbar-text` :http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-text

Answer (score 0):

Dont understand the goal entirely but let me take a crack at it... It sounds like you want more than just menu items to collapse...Right? Great! See below

--> http://www.bootply.com/118940

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

everything inside of

```
class="collapse navbar-collapse"
```

will collapse...

see it here --> http://www.bootply.com/118940